# initscript CentOS launching chroot nginx problems

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, chroot

I found this initscript for launching nginx here: http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/centos-adding-an-nginx-init-script. Im trying to modify it to work with a chroot environment and its proving more troublesome than I expected.

Here's what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
#    
# nginx - this script starts and stops the nginx daemin
#
# chkconfig:   - 85 15 
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
. /etc/sysconfig/network

[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

nginx="/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx"
prog="nginx"
chroot="/usr/sbin/chroot /nginx
NGINX_CONF_FILE="/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf"

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/nginx

start() {
    [ -x $nginx ] || exit 5
    [ -f $NGINX_CONF_FILE ] || exit 6
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $chroot $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killall $prog
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    configtest || return $?
    stop
    start
}

reload() {
    configtest || return $?
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    killall $prog -HUP
    retval=$?
    echo
}

force_reload() {
    restart
}

configtest() {
    $nginx -t -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE 
}

rh_status() {
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        if rh_status_q; then
            printf "$prog already running\n"
            exit 0
        fi
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        if ! rh_status_q; then
            printf "$prog not running\n"
            exit 0
        fi
        $1
        ;;
    restart|configtest)
        $1
        ;;
    reload)
        if ! rh_status_q; then
            printf "$prog not running\n"
            exit 7
        fi
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload)
        force_reload
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        if ! rh_status_q; then
            printf "$prog not running\n"
            exit 0
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|configtest}"
        exit 2
esac
```

The main thing not working right now is the status call. 
    [root@localhost ~]# /etc/init.d/nginx status
    nginx dead but subsys locked

This error points to a lockfile being present but no pid file. This is true, however when I use the original nginx init script and launch it in a non-chroot environment, there is no pidfile, and the status call works just fine.

I put in some lines to retrieve the pid by launching the process in the background instead of using daemon:
    PID=`$chroot $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE > /dev/null 2>&1 $ echo $!`
    echo $PID > $pidfile

But this grabs the pid of chroot, which ends after nginx is launched. Nginx has both a master and a child pid. Might grabbing those and putting them to a pidfile be the way forward? Or is there something else I should try?

I think its because daemon launches a chroot process it gets the wrong pid.

Answer (score 0):

Alright it was as easy as grepping for the pid

```
pidfile='/var/run/nginx.pid'

start(){
    ...
    daemon $chroot $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
    PID=`ps -ef | grep $nginx | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo $PID > $pidfile
    ...
}
stop() {
    ...
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile && rm -f $pidfile
    return $retval
}
```